# How to do double case / switch statement in SQL SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a very simple table with only two fields, here is what it looks like:

```
+-------+------------+
| State |   Value    |
+-------+------------+
| CT    | 93686.80   |
| MO    | 49109.00   |
| SD    | 2155.00    |
| AL    | 105598.20  |
```

Then in SSRS, I have a switch statement that determines the color of a textbox based on the value.

Here is that

```
=SWITCH 
(
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >= 1500000,"#920000",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >= 1000000,"#a30000",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=  500000,"#ac1919",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=  200000,"#b53232",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=  100000,"#be4c4c",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=   50000,"#c76666",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=   25000,"#d17f7f",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=   10000,"#da9999",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=    5000,"#e3b2b2",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=    2500,"#eccccc",
 Min(Fields!Value.Value, "CustomersByState") >=    1000,"#f5e5e5",
 1=1,"#ffffff"
 )
```

What I want to add is add another iff statement wrapping that to check if it is a certain state like CA or NY. How can I do that? This is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
 =IIF(First(Fields!State.Value, "Customers") = "CA",
(
    SWITCH 
    (
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >= 1500000,"#920000",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >= 1000000,"#a30000",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=  500000,"#ac1919",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=  200000,"#b53232",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=  100000,"#be4c4c",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=   50000,"#c76666",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=   25000,"#d17f7f",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=   10000,"#da9999",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=    5000,"#e3b2b2",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=    2500,"#eccccc",
     Min(Fields!Value.Value, "Customers") >=    1000,"#f5e5e5",
     1=1,"#ffffff"
     )
 )
 ,"#ffffff")
```

I am getting a weird XML buffer error. Although that might be related to something else. Can someone tell me if that above code is correct? Baiscally I'm filling in each polygon of a state in an SSRS map and I want to color it by the value of the state.

Comment: Two things, it's `IIF`, not `IFF`.  Second, if this is being entered in one of the color properties, you'll need to set the false condition to a color code.  So replace the `0` with something like `#ffffff`.

Comment: I think you have a parenthesis in the wrong place.  `iif((Fields!State.Value, "CustomersByState" = "CA"),`.  Though I don't know if that is relevant.

Comment: @Steve-o169 Thanks! Does it seem right otherwise? I would just like to make sure before I go and copy and paste it to the 50 different states.

Comment: avery found another potential issue -- you'll need to use an aggregate or some function in front of that `Fields!State.Value` conditional.  Try `=IIF(First(Fields!State.Value, "CustomersByState") = "CA", (SWITCH(...` Otherwise, it looks like it should work.

Comment: But if I use first (or any other aggregate), won't it always return one state? I have multiple boxes I want to apply this query too where I change CA to NY or NJ and so on. Like imagine 10 different text boxes representing 10 states, and for the color of each I want to put that expression so it will color the box according to it's states value.

Comment: I guess you wouldn't be able to specify a scope in that case.  Is there a way to add this entire thing to a list item to specify the dataset that way?

Comment: I just pivoted the table so every state was it's own column and now everything seems to be working.